Transaction failing due to Out of gas
My transaction is failing due to Out of gas. Here is the transaction:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x84577314e676382314b620d79fba2353cbb7962ed97071f404f81010bf56ea32
I'm using hardhat to deploy my contracts and ethers.js to interact wit them. The call to VRF is successful and I'm able to get the request Id. But the transaction is failing before callback by VRF happens. How can I increase gas Limit so that transaction becomes successful?
Here is my contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {VRFV2PlusWrapperConsumerBase} from "./vrf/VRFV2PlusWrapperConsumerBase.sol";
import {LinkTokenInterface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
import {VRFV2PlusClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract CertificateSepolia is
    ERC721URIStorage,
    VRFV2PlusWrapperConsumerBase,
    Ownable
{
    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);

    event CertificateMintSuccessfull();

    event RequestFulfilled(
        uint256 requestId,
        uint256[] randomWords,
        uint256 payment
    );

    struct RequestStatus {
        uint256 paid; // amount paid in link
        bool fulfilled; // whether the request has been successfully fulfilled
        uint256[] randomWords;
    }

    struct CertificateRequest {
        address studentAddress;
        string tokenURI;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */

    mapping(uint256 => CertificateRequest)
        public s_certificateRequests; /* requestId --> certificateRequest */

    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 400000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 constant numWords = 1;
    address immutable i_wrapperAddress;
    address immutable i_linkAddress;

    uint256 internal tokenId;
    uint256 maxSupplyOfToken = 3000;

    //collection name, symbol
    constructor(
        address _linkAddress,
        address _wrapperAddress
    )
        ERC721("Certificate", "CERT")
        VRFV2PlusWrapperConsumerBase(_wrapperAddress)
    {
        i_linkAddress = _linkAddress;
        i_wrapperAddress = _wrapperAddress;
    }

    function requestRandomWords() internal returns (uint256) {
        console.log("Requesting random number");
        // choosing payments in LINK
        bytes memory extraArgs = VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(
            VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: false})
        );

        console.log("Successfully prepared extra Args");

        (uint256 requestId, uint256 requestPrice) = requestRandomness(
            callbackGasLimit,
            requestConfirmations,
            numWords,
            extraArgs
        );

        console.log("Successfully got request Id");

        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            paid: requestPrice,
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            fulfilled: false
        });
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        console.log("Inside fulfill random words");
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;
        emit RequestFulfilled(
            _requestId,
            _randomWords,
            s_requests[_requestId].paid
        );
        tokenId = s_requests[_requestId].randomWords[0];
        tokenId = getValidAvailableTokenId(tokenId);
        address to = s_certificateRequests[_requestId].studentAddress;
        string memory tokenURI = s_certificateRequests[_requestId].tokenURI;
        // mint certificate NFT to student address
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
        console.log("NFT successfully minted for student");
        emit CertificateMintSuccessfull();
    }

    function getValidAvailableTokenId(
        uint256 randomTokenId
    ) internal returns (uint256) {
        randomTokenId = randomTokenId % maxSupplyOfToken;
        randomTokenId = checkIfTokenIdAlreadyExists(randomTokenId);
        if (randomTokenId == maxSupplyOfToken) {
            //increase max token supply
            maxSupplyOfToken = maxSupplyOfToken + 1000;
            // again look for valid token Id by mod of original long token Id
            return getValidAvailableTokenId(tokenId);
        }
        return randomTokenId;
    }

    // check if token id already exists and return an available token id
    function checkIfTokenIdAlreadyExists(
        uint256 shortTokenId
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 start = shortTokenId;
        if (_exists(shortTokenId)) {
            while (_exists(shortTokenId) && shortTokenId < maxSupplyOfToken) {
                shortTokenId = shortTokenId + 1;
            }
            if (shortTokenId == maxSupplyOfToken) {
                shortTokenId = 0;
            } else {
                return shortTokenId;
            }
            while (_exists(shortTokenId) && shortTokenId < start) {
                shortTokenId = shortTokenId + 1;
            }
            if (shortTokenId == start) {
                console.log(
                    "All available token Ids have been used. Need to increase max supply of token Ids"
                );
                return maxSupplyOfToken;
            } else {
                return shortTokenId;
            }
        }
        return shortTokenId;
    }

    function getRequestStatus(
        uint256 _requestId
    )
        external
        view
        returns (uint256 paid, bool fulfilled, uint256[] memory randomWords)
    {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        RequestStatus memory request = s_requests[_requestId];
        return (request.paid, request.fulfilled, request.randomWords);
    }

    function mint(address to, string memory _tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        console.log("Reached mint function in Certificate contract");
        uint256 requestId = requestRandomWords();
        console.log("Got the VRF Request Id");
        s_certificateRequests[requestId] = CertificateRequest({
            studentAddress: to,
            tokenURI: _tokenURI
        });
        console.log("Waiting for random number to be returned.");
    }

    function withdrawLink() external onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(i_linkAddress);
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }

    function getCallbackGasLimit() public view returns (uint32) {
        return callbackGasLimit;
    }

    function setCallbackGasLimit(uint32 _gasLimit) external onlyOwner {
        callbackGasLimit = _gasLimit;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public view returns (uint16) {
        return requestConfirmations;
    }

    function setRequestConfirmations(
        uint16 _requestConfirmations
    ) external onlyOwner {
        requestConfirmations = _requestConfirmations;
    }

    function getWrapperAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return i_wrapperAddress;
    }

    function getLinkAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return i_linkAddress;
    }
}


do you mind verifying and publishing the contract code? that way we might be able to pinpoint the problem better,  Your call seems okay so the issue might be within the mint function logic

@Casareafer I've added contract code to my question.

In tx you provided here, you are trying to call mint function in your smart contract. The transaction failed so it does not mean "The call to VRF is successful". Since you add VRF request within the mint function, the VRF request might failed. If you cannot send VRF request successfully, maybe check if you are using the correct wrapper address and have enough LINK balance in your smart contract.

@FrankKong The VRF request is actually working perfectly. I'm able to get back request Id. But before the request can get fulfilled, the transaction goes out of gas.

I found the way to override gas Limit.
I'm using hardhat-deploy plugin along with hardhat.
This is the correct way to set gas limit:
const { ethers, getNamedAccounts, deployments } = require("hardhat");

      const receiverStudentAddress = "";
      const ipfsTokenURI = "";
      const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
      const { execute } = deployments;
    
      const receipt = await execute(
        "CertificateSepolia",
        { from: deployer, gasLimit: 400000 },
        "mint",
        receiverStudentAddress,
        ipfsTokenURI
      );
      console.log(receipt);


It says failed for out of gas on the transaction 296,658 (100%). Rerunning with 318,664, passes.

Might consider using the method eth_estimateGas, then adding a slight buffer to the result, as will only take what is needed, while if not enough will consume what was used up to that point.
You'll want to use that value under gas in the transaction parameter when calling, it isn't set from inside the contract code.
Example:

js/webbrowser

const calldata = "0xd0def52100000000000000000000000069a12b5b6ba42462425d1153ac411f6bee374e350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004368747470733a2f2f697066732e696f2f697066732f516d614375556850556b456f656e6e48584677696a69595275654432445969483677615a3744714b52314d4763470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

const txParams = {
 from: '0xd383ccf184830d26c3f6a8656f84193934385cfb',
 to: '0xb3a8526a1116eaa76288f31f39bbac72239a78a4',
 gas: 500000 // <----
 value: 0,
 data: calldata
};


Do I need to set gas parameter in hardhat.config.js?

I add this to hardhat config file.
sepolia: {       url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,       accounts: [SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],       chainId: 11155111,       blockConfirmations: 3,       gas: 500000,     },
But this does not work. Any idea why? The gas limit is not getting increased.

Also why in the screenshot that you've put the gas limit is being shown as 38,842,550 but in tx params you want me to pass 500000? Sorry for asking these questions, I've recently started learning blockchain.

Also @Maka how did you re run this?

https://tenderly.co is the tool in the screenshot. You said you were using ethers.js to interact with the contract, can't you set it in the transaction parameters? I don't use hardhat, that looks ok based on the example config but if it's only relevant when you deploy the contract, why should it effect anything when you are calling?

For the 38,842,550. That is just max gas limit so I could easily see the amount it wanted without doing an estimateGas first. Quick way to see if there is a deeper issue.

Thanks @Maka for your efforts.
